# Don't show hours in 1 month zoom Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to hide the hours when zoomed to 1 month.

I have a demo here: http://dev.feldsam.cz/unipetrol-stock/

I tried to use `tickPositioner`:

```
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {                
    var diff = max - min;

    // month
    if(diff <= 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 && diff > 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
        var date = new Date(max);
        var minus = date.getHours() * 3600 * 1000;
        max = max - minus;

        var pos,
        tickPositions = [],
        tickStart = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).getTime();

        for (pos = tickStart; pos <= max; pos += (5 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)) {
            tickPositions.push(pos);
        }

        tickPositions.info = {
            unitName: "day",
            higherRanks: {} 
        };

        this.options.ordinal = false;

        return tickPositions;
    } else {
        this.options.ordinal = true;
    }
}
```

But the hours are still showing. Also, when I click from one month to another, ordinal is still false.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it in dateTimeLabelFormat http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats